# iOS 14.1 Facing issue with keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, key, swift4

[Keyboard keys not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca9wz.png)

Hello, all I am facing an issue with the keyboard, when I tap on the textfield it opens the keyboard but the keys are not visible on the click it works but not visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the different options in the attributes inspector. Or try with another component if the issue still too.
Reboot the XCode, or try deploy your app with another device simulator.

[image]